# Android: MessagesFragment doesn't open after receiving command from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Main" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        MessagesFragment messagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.fragment_container , messagesFragment)
               .commit();
    }
};
```

I have passed this broadcast from Recyclerview Adapter onClick to MainActivity . When I click on each item, I can see the toast but the MessagesFragment doesn't start..

Comment: Why did you use BroadcastReceiver in adapter to activity? If you want to communicate with the activity, then it will be incorrect use of `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: i need to open a fragment after clicking on each item. That's the way i used to solve this problem but it didn't work! What can i do?

Comment: You need to use Listener for that. Don't use BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Yeah i know that. my listener works but the issue is that i cannot open new fragment inside Adapter. i had to use broadcast to pass command to Activity and start fragment from there..

Comment: You should not open fragment inside Adapter. That responsibility should be handled by the Activity.

Comment: Can you explain what should i do please?

Comment: I made an answer that will slightly explain how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not using `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate with Activity from an Adapter. Instead, you need to use Listener/Callback. You can follow something like below.

First, modify your Adapter to add an interface as the listener:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    // ...

    // Create the listener.
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    // Define the listener interface
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    // define the listener to be used by the Activity.
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            ...
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, in your **Activity** where the adapter reside, you need to set the listener:

```
YourAdapter adapter = ...;
// populate the adapter
// and anything related to the adapter initialization.

// then set the listener 
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new YourAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        // Do something when clicked.
        MessagesFragment messagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.fragment_container , messagesFragment)
               .commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: now i have got this error


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.google.com.api/www.google.com.api.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void www.google.com.api.RoomsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(www.google.com.api.RoomsAdapter$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: have you populate your adapter? Looks like you haven't initialize your RoomsAdapter

Comment: You need to populate the adapter and set it to the RecylerView as usual. Then, add the `adapter.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: thank you , no i have one problem. i have an viewpager that lets me swipe between to fragments. recyclerview is inside one fragment. when i click , the view pager doesnt close although i see the toast of my click..